# Problems returning address through geolocation

Tags: react-native, geocode

I'm trying to use the [react-native-geocoder](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-geocoder) library to return the address through the latitude and longitude of the device.

Through response to another question and some more research, I came up with this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
  AppRegistry, 
  View, 
  Text
} from 'react-native';
import Geocoder from 'react-native-geocoder'; // 0.5.0

Geocoder.apiKey = '__API__KEY__';

export default class testeGeocoder extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
      place: 'Localizando endereço...',
      error: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      (position) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        });
      },
      (error) => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
    );

    Geocoder.geocodePosition(this.state.latitude,this.state.longitude)
      .then(res => {
          this.setState({
              place: res[0].formatedAddress
          });
          console.log(res[0].formattedAddress)
      });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
        <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.place.toString()}</Text>
        {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('testeGeocoder', () => testeGeocoder);
```

But this returns me to the correct latitude and longitude, but stays locating address ... and never returns.

**Edit:**

With the help of bennygenel and Michael Cheng I managed to eliminate the warning and got to this code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { 
  AppRegistry, 
  View, 
  Text
} from 'react-native';
import Geocoder from 'react-native-geocoder'; // 0.5.0

Geocoder.apiKey = '__API__KEY__';

export default class teste47 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      latitude: null,
      longitude: null,
      place: 'Localizando endereço...',
      error: null,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
   navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    position => {
      this.setState(
        {
          latitude: position.coords.latitude,
          longitude: position.coords.longitude,
          error: null,
        },
        () => {
          Geocoder.geocodePosition({
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
          }).then(res => {
            this.setState({
              place: res[0].formattedAddress,
            });
          });
        }
      );
    },
    error => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
    { 
      enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000 
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flexGrow: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
        <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
        <Text>{this.state.place.toString()}</Text>
        {this.state.error ? <Text>Error: {this.state.error}</Text> : null}
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('teste47', () => teste47);
```

But when I execute this it is returning the error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: One last comment, you may want to edit out that API key from the question or just revoke it and make a new one. It's probably not something you want to be public ;) Revoking will probably be the safer bet since I'm not sure if it's possible to make edits that won't save in history on StackOverflow.

Comment: @MichaelCheng Can not I see the problem of seeing the key? Is it a free public key that I created just for example, in the application I use another, is there anything that can do that would harm me?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of how you generated the key, but in general practice, even if you don't reuse the API Key, you don't want just anyone using your keys. There are usually limitations to your keys and excessive usage could cause you to hit your threshold. See: [Google Maps Geocoding API Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/usage-limits).

Answer (score 2):

`Geocoder.geocodePosition` takes an object contains `lat` and `long`. You are trying to send 2 separate parameters.

If you change

```
Geocoder.geocodePosition(this.state.latitude, this.state.longitude)
  .then(res = > {
    this.setState({
      place: res[0].formattedAddress
    });
    console.log(res[0].formattedAddress)
  });
```

to this

```
Geocoder.geocodePosition({ lat: this.state.latitude, long: this.state.longitude})
  .then(res = > {
    this.setState({
      place: res[0].formattedAddress
    });
    console.log(res[0].formattedAddress)
  });
```

error will be solved.

**Side Note 1:** When using Promise it is a really good practice to handle error with `catch`.

```
Geocoder.geocodePosition({ lat: this.state.latitude, long: this.state.longitude})
  .then(res = > {
    // do something with response
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // do something with error
  });
```

**Side Note 2:** You also have `formatedAddress` misspelled. It should be corrected to `formattedAddress`.

**Side Note 3:** setState() is asynchronous. With the way you coded it, when `Geocoder.geocodePosition()` is called, you are not guaranteed to have your `latitude` and `longitude` defined in `state` yet. So you may want to change how that's done. One possible fix for this is to place it in the callback of `setState()` like so:

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  position => {
    this.setState(
      {
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude,
        error: null,
      },
      () => {
        Geocoder.geocodePosition({
          lat: this.state.latitude,
          lng: this.state.longitude,
        }).then(res => {
          this.setState({
            place: res[0].formattedAddress,
          });
        });
      }
    );
  },
  error => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
  { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
);
```

Comment: I made the changes you recommended and the error really disappeared, but it is not yet returning the address: https://snack.expo.io/HyfjKaiaZ

Comment: Two other things to add to this: 1) `formatedAddress` is misspelled. Should be `formattedAddress`. bennygenel corrected it in his log statement, but make sure to fix it in `setState()` as well. 2) `setState()` is asynchronous. With the way you coded it, when `Geocoder.geocodePosition()` is called, you are not guaranteed to have your `latitude` and `longitude` defined in `state` yet. So you may want to change how that's done. One possible fix for this is to place it in the callback of `setState()`.

Comment: I think I have edit privileges so I'll edit an example into the answer.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help, I made the recommended changes, but now I have to find out why you are falling in Error: `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'i.geocodePosition')` https://snack.expo.io/H1h10aipZ

Comment: @Mate you did not made the changes on your snack I believe.

Comment: @bennygenel I think I did not save, but here it is: https://snack.expo.io/r18t-A3pb

Comment: @Mate this is kinda my mistake. I just noticed that react-native-geocode need to be linked so it doesn't work with expo and create-react-native-app.

Comment: @bennygenel I'll try to create and run in an AVD here then

Comment: @Mate unless you started your app with `react-native-cli` it doesn't change anything. You need to [detach](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/detach.html) or [eject](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md) your app if you started with create-react-native-app or expo

Comment: @bennygenel I created with `react-native init`, that will be a problem?

Comment: @Mate nope. that how can you use packages that needs to be linked.

Comment: @bennygenel I found this issue now (https://github.com/devfd/react-native-geocoder/issues/25), so I understood `react-native link` maybe solve my problem

Comment: You are now presenting `Can not read property 'geocodePosition' of undefined`, should I open a new question, or edit that putting the current situation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157505/discussion-between-mate-and-bennygenel).